# Disparity between Mobile Tabstrip and Angular Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile

For Kendo Mobile TabStrip demos taken from the Kendo UI site, the default sample mobile tab is the following markup:

```
<div data-role="tabstrip" data-selected-index="1">
  <a data-icon="contacts">foo</a>
  <a data-icon="contacts">bar</a>
  <a data-icon="info">baz</a>
</div>
```

But the AngularJS equivalent is:

```
<kendo-mobile-view id="tabstrip-foo" k-title="'foo'" k-layout="'mobile-tabstrip'">
</kendo-mobile-view>
<kendo-mobile-view id="tabstrip-bar" k-title="'bar'" k-layout="'mobile-tabstrip'">
</kendo-mobile-view>
<kendo-mobile-view id="tabstrip-baz" k-title="'baz'" k-layout="'mobile-tabstrip'">
</kendo-mobile-view>
```

Why the disparity between formats?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which demo you are looking at, but the Angular elements there are defining the views that the tabstrip navigates to, not the tabstrip itself.

[This demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-tabstrip/angular) has the HTML:

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip">
        <a href="#tabstrip-profile" data-icon="contacts">Profile
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-sales" data-icon="history">Sales
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-rating" data-icon="favorites">Rating
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-settings" data-icon="settings">Settings</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or the Angular version:

```
<kendo-mobile-footer>
    <kendo-mobile-tab-strip>
        <a href="#tabstrip-profile" data-icon="contacts">Profile
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-sales" data-icon="history">Sales
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-rating" data-icon="favorites">Rating
        </a><a href="#tabstrip-settings" data-icon="settings">Settings</a>
    </kendo-mobile-tab-strip>
</kendo-mobile-footer>
```

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood and that makes sense.  But why he disparity in tags and structure?  Why "div" tag for one and "kendo-mobile-tab-strip" for the other??  Very little documentation out there from what I've been trying to find...

Comment: `kendo-mobile-tab-strip` is a custom Angular directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive that initializes the element to be a Kendo TabStrip.

Comment: Also this page is probably the most useful documentation: http://kendo-labs.github.io/angular-kendo/#/basics

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense but wasn't apparent to me.  It appears that I should also be able to use a div tag with a kendo-mobile-tab-strip attribute, which should also work?  Thx.

Comment: Yes Angular should interpret `<kendo-mobile-tab-strip>` and `<div kendo-mobile-tab-strip>` to be the same thing. That behavior is part of Angular not Kendo, just to be clear.